# Extracting data from dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here is an example of the data I'm working with.

```
{'etag': '"ld9biNPKjAjgjV7EZ4EKeEGrhao/1v2mrzYSYG6onNLt2qTj13hkQZk"',
 'items': [{'etag': '"ld9biNPKjAjgjV7EZ4EKeEGrhao/Xy1mB4_yLrHy_BmKmPBggty2mZQ"',
            'id': '1',
            'kind': 'youtube#videoCategory',
            'snippet': {'assignable': True,
                        'channelId': 'UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ',
                        'title': 'Film & Animation'}},
           {'etag': '"ld9biNPKjAjgjV7EZ4EKeEGrhao/UZ1oLIIz2dxIhO45ZTFR3a3NyTA"',
            'id': '2',
            'kind': 'youtube#videoCategory',
            'snippet': {'assignable': True,
                        'channelId': 'UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ',
                        'title': 'Autos & Vehicles'}},
           {'etag': '"ld9biNPKjAjgjV7EZ4EKeEGrhao/nqRIq97-xe5XRZTxbknKFVe5Lmg"',
            'id': '10',
            'kind': 'youtube#videoCategory',
            'snippet': {'assignable': True,
                        'channelId': 'UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ',
                        'title': 'Music'}},
 'kind': 'youtube#videoCategoryListResponse'}
```

I'd like to extract 2 columns of data

1. 'id'
2. 'title'

I.e., from the first item, I would have `'id' = 1, 'title' = Film & Animation`

I'm very new to Python, what would be the best way to do this in Python?

Thank you all so much!

Comment: That is not JSON, that's a dict.

Comment: It's not so hard, [check this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQfNYqz8pLs&t=937s) for accessing nested dictionary keys

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! That's great, that you've posted sample data, but please, add also your code snippets which you've been trying so far - to show your efforts and way, how you wanted to solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and recommendations, I'm new to both coding and Stack Overflow, so I will keep the above in mind in future.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's

```
for it in data['items']:
  print(it['id'], it['snippet']['title'])
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try. I really appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

'items' is a list of object you can iterate through it via for loop:

```
for item in your_data['items']:
    id = item['id']
    title = item['snippet']['title']
    print(id, title)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Guess there's a typo, `'items'` key, is a `list`, and whenever we start brackets (`[`) we need to close them (`]`).

```py
{'etag': '"ld9biNPKjAjgjV7EZ4EKeEGrhao/1v2mrzYSYG6onNLt2qTj13hkQZk"',
 'items': [{'etag': '"ld9biNPKjAjgjV7EZ4EKeEGrhao/Xy1mB4_yLrHy_BmKmPBggty2mZQ"',
            'id': '1',
            'kind': 'youtube#videoCategory',
            'snippet': {'assignable': True,
                        'channelId': 'UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ',
                        'title': 'Film & Animation'}},
           {'etag': '"ld9biNPKjAjgjV7EZ4EKeEGrhao/UZ1oLIIz2dxIhO45ZTFR3a3NyTA"',
            'id': '2',
            'kind': 'youtube#videoCategory',
            'snippet': {'assignable': True,
                        'channelId': 'UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ',
                        'title': 'Autos & Vehicles'}},
           {'etag': '"ld9biNPKjAjgjV7EZ4EKeEGrhao/nqRIq97-xe5XRZTxbknKFVe5Lmg"',
            'id': '10',
            'kind': 'youtube#videoCategory',
            'snippet': {'assignable': True,
                        'channelId': 'UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ',
                        'title': 'Music'}},     # <-----  HERE, no brackets
 'kind': 'youtube#videoCategoryListResponse'}
```

### List Comprehension

```py
# all items
[row for row in data['items']]   

# custom data from all items
[(row['id'], row['snippet']['title']) for row in data['items']]     

# just id > 0 (filtering data)
[row for row in data['items'] if row['id']>0]
```

combine both filtering data extracting special fields:

```py
[(r['id'], r['snippet']['title']) for r in data['items'] if r['id'] > 0]
```

### Also give `filter` a Chance

**it's really cool**

```py
f = lambda r: (r['id'], r['snippet']['title'])
result = filter(f, data['items'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive solutions! I'll give these a try. I am very very new to Python so I really appreciate this.